# Ignore dependencies inside Browserify require

Tags: javascript, browserify, laravel-elixir

The problem I am having is using moment js in combination with a bootstrap date picker plugin (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I am using Laravel Elixir Version 3 and Gulp to broswerify:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
mix
    .browserify('app.js')
```

In my app.js I was trying to use it as below:

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
global.moment = require('moment');
require('bootstrap');
require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');
```

However as eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker tries to detect if it is being loaded inside Browserify and instead then automatically tries to resolve its dependencies itself and loads both jQuery and its own version of moment js.

This would not be too much of an issue but I need to use my version of moment which also has specific locales added to it.

I have tried many solutions detailed on here and elsewhere one notably being using browserify shim. The only way at the moment this seems to be solved is by moving everything to their own global space.

Any pointers would be great and if anything isn't clear let me know and I will update the question, thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but the ` --no-bundle-external` option might be handy: [browserify docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage)

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that but appears to prevent every single require from being included? For example in my main app.js var Vue = require('vue'); now appears to result in module not found.